# How to cancel timerTask for AsyncTask in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, timertask

Hi I am working on TCP socket.
I can read data for every 1 sec. to achieve it I used TimerTask as shown in below code.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Timer timer = new Timer();

TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            finalizer = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (navBool) {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    new RetriveStock().execute(); // AsyncTask.
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            };
            handler.post(finalizer);
        }
    }; 
timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 1000);
```

For canceling this timer I used code as

```
timer.cancel();
timer = null;
handler.removeCallbacks(finalizer);
```

But it is not cancelling the timer. I do not know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `timer.cancel()`, you should be canceling the task that is assigned to that timer (`doAsynchronousTask` in your case).  Since multiple TimerTasks can be assigned to one timer, calling `timer.cancel()` will not interfere with a currently running task.

From the [Timer JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel%28%29):

> `public void cancel()`
>
> Terminates this timer, discarding any currently scheduled tasks. Does
> not interfere with a currently executing task (if it exists). Once a
> timer has been terminated, its execution thread terminates gracefully,
> and no more tasks may be scheduled on it.

Comment: How can I cancel the current running task also.?

Comment: In your case, `doAsynchronousTask.cancel(true)`.  (The `true` parameter indicates that the call to `cancel()` can preempt the thread if it's currently executing).