# Is it necessary to close all the background threads in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

In Android, is it necessary to close or stop all the running background threads  before the app closes?  If yes then how to do that?

I have multiple thread in my program. Say I am running some xyz operation on the first background thread. The problem that I am facing is that even after some time xyz operation on first background is still running, so I thought of stopping that thread explicitly.

Comment: should we close the background thread before app close ??

Comment: In this case, your thread is terminated immediately. The sendPacket() method is not called.

Answer (score 1):

> is it necessary to close/stop all the background thread

It depends on what do you need.

> how to do that?

You use `TimerTask` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663606/how-to-cancel-timertask-for-asynctask-in-android) how to cancel), `AsyncTask` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735102/ideal-way-to-cancel-an-executing-asynctask) how to cancel), `Thread` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505707/android-best-and-safe-way-to-stop-thread) how to cancel), `Runnable` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188398/how-to-stop-runnable-on-button-click-in-android) how to cancel) ?

Comment: thing is I am running some xyz operation on say first background thread( i have multiple thread in my program )  problem that I am facing is tat even after some time xyz operation on first background keeps running, so thought of closing that thread after some thing ??

Comment: you may close operation if task was completed or you do not need it any more

Answer (score 0):

See @kirthan,

Your application always working on main-thread,
sub threads of your application are mostly close after them work completed automatically instead of some special case.

but suppose you want to terminate between the working thread  follow  [vmarkeev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33750262/3513479) 
 answer.

Comment: Thank u bro !! then in java why is it necessary to close the thread ??

Comment: see android basically work on core java, actually same concepts. but in some of case you must close thread. all object oriented thread even machine thread also stop automatically after  completed task. that's behavior of thread

Comment: for example one car is running on road while petrol is there. as like thread is running while the task is there.

Answer (score -2):

You can use interrupt() to stop any thread

Comment: Which context do you mean? Application context, component context, process context? In either case, the answer is wrong, or in best case incomplete.

Comment: Your edited answer is completely different from your first answer. Edits should be used to refine an answer, not rewrite it. Oh, and don't be put down by the negative remarks you get here. Just give it some thought and I'm sure that your next answer will get positive response.